# Data-structure of Pairs where each value (in pair) Maps to other value?

Tags: java, data-structures, dictionary

I'm back again with a similar question. Is there a DataType that can return its specific partner? For example:

```
ExampleType<String,String> test = new ExampleType<String,String>();
test.put("hello","hi");
```

If I were to type test.get("hi"), it would return "hello", and if I were to type test.get("hello"), it would return "hi".

My only guess for this would maybe be a two dimensional array, but I'm not sure how I would implement this. As of right now, the only way I can understand of doing this is creating two different hashmaps and swapping the keys in each. (obviously this is not very efficient/effective).

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Sometimes what is "obvious" is in the eye of the beholder.  A pair of maps sounds just fine to me.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the [Guava's BiMap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html) for this. It supports inverse lookup as well:

> A bimap (or "bidirectional map") is a map that preserves the uniqueness of its values as well as that of its keys. This constraint enables bimaps to support an "inverse view", which is another bimap containing the same entries as this bimap but with reversed keys and values.

If you already have a dependency on commons-collections then you can also use `BidiMap`.

Comment: +1 For library suggestion. However note that the additional constraint may make this not suitable for all similar tasks. (It is a 1-1 map, not a 1-N with reverse-lookup map.)

Answer (score 3):

Nothing built in, so you either use a 3rd party package like Guava's BiMap mentioned by Pangea, or, if you want to roll your own, if you need two distinct data types, the 2-maps idea is not bad, if your keys and values are the same type you can use a single map with doubled entries:

```
public class BiMap<T>{

    private Map<T,T> theMap = new HashMap<T,T>();

    public void put( T key, T value ){ put( key, value, false ); }
    public void forcePut( T key, T value ){ put( key, value, true ); }

    private void put( T key, T value, boolean force ){
        if( force || !theMap.containsKey(value) ){
            theMap.remove( theMap.remove( key ) );
            theMap.put( key, value );
            theMap.put( value, key );
        }else if( !theMap.get( value ).equals( key ) ){
            // If you allow null values&keys this will get more complicated.

            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
            // can make this more informative.
        }
        // else the pair is already in, there's nothing to do.
    }

    public T get( T key ){ return theMap.get( key ); }

    public T remove( T key ){
        T value = theMap.remove( key );
        if( value != null ) theMap.remove( value );
        return value;
    }
}
```

Notice that because everything is an object, there isn't much waste as far as efficiency/space is concerned: the only things you're storing twice are object addresses. The same goes for your 2-map idea.

Also it wouldn't be too hard to add the necessary methods to make this implement the `Map<T,T>` interface for compliance's sake.

Comment: I might go so far as to extend `HashMap<T,T>`

Comment: That has "surprising" behaviour if you `put` overlapping keys. `test.put("a", "b"); test.put("a", "c");` `test.get(test.get("b"))` doesn't return `"b"`.

Comment: Good catch. I'll correct it. What I have right now as `put` is a dirty `forcePut`.

Comment: I guess it isn't as elegant as I thought at first when you put in all the tests for weird cases.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you aren't intending to distinguish which part of the pair you're querying for (that is, you want to see

```
test.get("hi") => "hello"
test.get("hello") => "hi"
```

why not just insert both keys into the same map?

```
test.put("hello","hi");
test.put("hi","hello");
```

Answer (score -1):

Two ArrayLists would probably be the easiest..  Just make sure you store the pairs in the same index and it should work fine.  Code would look something like:

```
ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();
list1.add("hi");
list2.add("hello");
get("hi");
```

and your get method:

```
get(String s){
    return list2.get( list1.indexOf(s) );
}
```

Don't know if this is the best solution, but it is a solution.

Comment: This is a very weak solution. He's already using Maps, so why throw out continued use of Maps?